# Is it possible to pass a parameter to an Action that is stored as a value in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net

Say I have a `Dictionary`:

```
var example = new Dictionary<string, Action>{ {"foo", Foo() } };
```

And `Foo`'s method signature looks like:

```
public static void Foo(string text)
```

Is it possible to pass a parameter to `Foo` when invoking from the dictionary?

Comment: ...and you also mean `{"foo", Foo }`. The only thing we don't know where that parameter should come from you wish to pass to Foo. Is the parameter the key string "foo"? ;-)

Comment: I apologize for using a string for the key and parameter in this example. I see how that could be confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If changing the `TValue` of your dictionary is acceptable then you need it to be  `Action<string>` so that you can store delegates which accept a single string parameter:

```
var example = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>{ { "foo", Foo } };
```

And use it like this:

```
example["foo"].Invoke("argument1");
```

If the dictionary must stay as is, then you can wrap the call to `Foo` into a Lambda expression, provided you know the value which needs to be passed as the argument to `Foo` at the time of adding it to the dictionary:

```
var example = new Dictionary<string, Action>{ { "foo", () => Foo("argument1") } };
example["foo"].Invoke();
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.

To clarify for anyone that has more than one element in their dictionary, you can also invoke by using the key:
    example["foo"].Invoke("somestring");

Comment: @SchwiftyPython Thank you for the feedback. I agree that retrieving the element by key makes for a more readable example so I've modified the answer. To further aid readability I've also changed the argument to the Action from "foo" to "argument1".

Answer (score 3):

You could use a lambda expression to do that, like:

```
var example = new Dictionary<string, Action> { { "foo", () => Foo("MyString") } };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var example = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>{ { "foo", Foo } };

public static void Foo(string text) {}

public static void CallAnAction(string key, string parameter)
{
    example[key](parameter);
}
```

It's also possible to call a Func and get a return value:

```
var example = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, bool>>{ { "foo", Foo } };

public static bool Foo(string text)
{
    return true;
}

public static bool CallAFunc(string key, string parameter)
{
    return example[key](parameter);
}
```